# Signed APK not working in Playstore for android 9 device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an app that I build using Ionic. The app work when i directly
install the sign and zip APK to any device. These device include the
Android 9 simulator, an Android 9 device and also an Android 6 device
.

But the app failed to connect to my database/api after I upload it to
Play Store. It always stuck when it is in the login authentication
splash screen.

Strangely, it only affect android 9, and not in android 6 (my current
phone) device but when I gave the user the signed and zip APK directly
to my colleague Android 9, the app works perfectly fine. My target user are
all outside my country that I'm from and it is not a very proper way
to just past along the APK to them.

Comment: Did you have the previous app in play store?

Comment: Just remove the web view plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also facing the same problem, I come out from this problem following way

Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `platforms->android->app->src->main` and add follwoing code in the application selector.

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

the final resultant selector will be

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

and make you have the correct access to Internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope it will solve your problem !!

Comment: Sorry I did not reply earlier. This part

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

solve my problem. It looks like Android 9 implements more security,

Thank you Sir.

Comment: sorry sir my reputation does not allow me. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". I think its because I'm a first time poster. Sad because your solution really save me.